# Android: easiest way to create a FIFO data storage?

Tags: android, data-storage

I want to store data in the following format:

```
file_name(string) | full_path(string) | file_type(string)
```

Besides having that format, I want this storage to work by FIFO method: inserting a new row goes "before" all other rows.

I considered using plain files, but I'm not sure how I would implement a FIFO method there without using a "id" column (to identify which came first).

Is there a simple approach to this issue without using database?

Comment: Why not databases? Databases would be the simplest way to do this by far.

Comment: Is using databases the simplest way to do this? If so, I'll go with databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the "overkill" of a DB and using a file instead to make things "lighter", just don't. SQLite is, at the end of the day, one single file, light and optimised, and what you are going to do is create your own "database" stored in a file.

Create a SQLlite database, which is trivial in android, and you have your FIFO for free, standard inserts will go to the end, and retrievals you can get what you want combining ORDER BY, DESC, and LIMIT to suit your needs. Is a single, simple, SQL SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You said "FIFO method: inserting a new row goes "before" all other rows."

Did you mean LIFO? If you plan to add something before all other rows (and process it before all other rows) then it's LIFO .

Second question. Do you need a persistance? If you don't, a database will be huge overkill. All you need to do is to have object of [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class.

Comment: Yeah, I need persistence (the data has to stay when a user exits the app).

Comment: Actually, Stack is serializable. If you will create a serializable class with file name, full path and file type, you can serialize/deserialize it (whole stack) to a file. I believe amount of code and complexity will be less than a database usage.